# AWS Wrangler S3 reading parquet, writing to DynamoDB - Unsupported type numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-dynamodb, aws-data-wrangler

I am trying to read parquet into dataframe with AWS wrangler, while writing this data to DynamoDB its erroring out with unsupported type error - Unsupported type numpy.ndarray for value.......

```
wr.s3.read_parquet(path=s3_path, dataset=dataset, chunked=True)

and writing like 

wr.dynamodb.put_df(df=df, table_name=table_name)
```

Is there a way, I can convert the ndarray type to dynamoDB list ? I dont want to lose the readability of the array if I use np.tobytes() to write and np.frombuffer() to read again. Also, users will not have access Numpy to read the data from DynamoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to get the answer, so it worked like this for me using tolist()-

```
df["key"] = df["key"].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())

wr.dynamodb.put_df(df, "test_table")
```